# Focus event is triggered in a Div element when the div itself is selected or any nested input field - Angular

Tags: angular

In An angular APP, I have a Div with an index tab in it to make it selectable.
the Div contain a form with many fields, buttons ...
I want to trigger the focus event on the div whenever the div it self is selected or any field, text .... in the div is selected (the focus event must bubble to that div)

here in  [This exemple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewb5ib)   you can see that the div changes color when the div get's focus but it doesnt when the input field get's the focus

Comment: I don't whant to add an eventlistener  in the field because in my use case i have to many input fields in that div.

Comment: no :focus-within because dont work with edge https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the same  [stackblitz exemple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewb5ib?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)  change the focus event into (focusin) event and it will work